# PHP Populate Table Headers Based on Data from Database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `table_headers` database table that contains the `id`, `header` text, `parent_id`, and `order_number` that contains this data.

[image]

How do I loop to this record in such a way that it makes this kind of HTML?

```
        <tr>
            <th colspan='2'>Header 1</th>
            <th colspan='6'>Header 2</th>
            <th rowspan='3'>Header 3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th rowspan=2>H1 Child 1</th>
            <th rowspan=2>H1 Child 2</th>
            <th rowspan=2>h2 Child 1</th>
            <th colspan=4>h2 Child 2</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>H2 C2 C1</th>
            <th>H2 C2 C2</th>
            <th>H2 C2 C3</th>
            <th>H2 C2 C4</th>
        </tr>
```

That should result to this.

[image]

**Lastly, how to have an array that would contain the IDs of the lowest child just like this.**

```
$lowest_child[0]=4; //because the ID of `H1 Child 1` is 4
$lowest_child[1]=5; //because the ID of `H1 Child 2` is 5 and so on
$lowest_child[2]=;
$lowest_child[3]=;
$lowest_child[4]=;
$lowest_child[5]=;
$lowest_child[6]=;
$lowest_child[7]=;
```

Another Example Data Set using the answer provided by ggordon.
[image]

It outputs to this. It seems that the order number of children is not followed.
[image]

Comment: It looks like a code challenge. You can use a tree data structure whose nodes contain arrays. Your first step would be to build your tree and you would traverse your tree in Level-Order-Traversal later. Check this link to get more info about Level-Order-Traversal >>> https://www.yourdevopsguy.com/recursion-vs-iteration-13-ways-to-traverse-a-tree/#:~:text=13%20Ways%20To%20Traverse%20a%20Tree%201%20Pre-order,Recursive.%20...%206%20Post-Order%20Traversal%20%E2%80%93%20Iterative.%20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

This can be achieved after generating some helpful metadata. The code below traverses and builds a tree in an associative array. With the assistance of some helper functions `getRowSpan` and `getColSpan` the table is generated from the metadata. The `json` metadata generated has been included below.

In order to get the array of the lowest children. You simply need to use `$levels[$depth]` which will return an associative array of children at the lowest depth. The keys are the ids of the children.

### HTML/PHP Code

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$headings = []; # store heading data as array

$numOfRows = count($headings); # 3
$levels = [];
$depth = 0;
$subHeadings = [];
$levels[$depth]=[];
for($i=0;$i<$numOfRows;$i++){
   if($headings[$i]["parent_id"]==null){
      $headings[$i]["child_count"]=0;
      $headings[$i]["child_ids"]=[];
      $headings[$i]["depth"]=0;
      $levels[$depth][$headings[$i]["id"]]=$headings[$i];
   }else{
      $subHeadings[]=$headings[$i];
   }
}

while(count($subHeadings)>0){
   $depth++;
   $levels[$depth]=[];
   $subHeadingNext=[];
   foreach($subHeadings as $sub){
       if(
         isset( $levels[$depth-1][
             $sub["parent_id"]
         ])
       ){
           $levels[$depth-1][$sub["parent_id"]]["child_count"]++;
           $levels[$depth-1][$sub["parent_id"]]["child_ids"][]=$sub["id"];
           $sub["child_count"]=0;
           $sub["child_ids"]=[];
           $sub["depth"]=$depth;
           $levels[$depth][$sub["id"]]=$sub;
       }else{
           $subHeadingNext[] = $sub;
       }
   }
   $subHeadings=$subHeadingNext;
}

#echo json_encode($levels,true);
#colspan is total of all child nodes

function getColSpan($node,$levels){
    $childCount = $node["child_count"];
    $visitor = $node;
    $childrenIds = $visitor["child_ids"];
    
    foreach($childrenIds as $childId){
         
        $childCount+= getColspan($levels[$visitor["depth"]+1][$childId],$levels);
    }
    
    return $childCount;
}
#max depth - depth of last child
function getRowSpan($node,$maxDepth){
   return $node["child_count"] > 0 ? 1 : $maxDepth - $node["depth"]+1;
}


?> 

<table border="3">
<?php
foreach($levels as $level => $nodes){
?>
<tr>
<?php
   foreach($nodes as $node){
       ?>
       <td colspan="<?php echo getColSpan($node,$levels)  ?>" rowspan="<?php echo getRowSpan($node,$depth)  ?>"><?php echo $node["header"] ?></td>
       <?php
   }
?>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

### Output

```html
<table border="3">
<tbody><tr>
       <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">Header 1</td>
              <td colspan="6" rowspan="1">Header 2</td>
              <td colspan="0" rowspan="3">Header 3</td>
       </tr>
<tr>
       <td colspan="0" rowspan="2">H1 Child 1</td>
              <td colspan="0" rowspan="2">H1 Child 2</td>
              <td colspan="0" rowspan="2">H2 Child 1</td>
              <td colspan="4" rowspan="1">H2 Child 2</td>
       </tr>
<tr>
       <td colspan="0" rowspan="1">H2-C2-C1</td>
              <td colspan="0" rowspan="1">H2-C2-C2</td>
              <td colspan="0" rowspan="1">H2-C2-C3</td>
              <td colspan="0" rowspan="1">H2-C2-C4</td>
       </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

### JSON Meta Data Generated

This is the processed result stored in `$levels`. It is an associated array. Each level starting from `0` can be accessed using `$levels[0]`. Within each level there is another associative array with  nodes/`tr`/table cells/headings . Each heading node is indexed by the id i.e. to get `Heading 1` we would use `$levels[0][1]`. You may see the additional metadata (depth, child ids and children count) generated and stored below:

```json
[
    {
        "1":{
            "id":"1",
            "header":"Header 1",
            "parent_id":null,
            "order_number":"1",
            "child_count":2,
            "child_ids":[
                "4",
                "5"
            ],
            "depth":0
        },
        "2":{
            "id":"2",
            "header":"Header 2",
            "parent_id":null,
            "order_number":"1",
            "child_count":2,
            "child_ids":[
                "6",
                "7"
            ],
            "depth":0
        },
        "3":{
            "id":"3",
            "header":"Header 3",
            "parent_id":null,
            "order_number":"1",
            "child_count":0,
            "child_ids":[
                
            ],
            "depth":0
        }
    },
    {
        "4":{
            "id":"4",
            "header":"H1 Child 1",
            "parent_id":"1",
            "order_number":"1",
            "child_count":0,
            "child_ids":[
                
            ],
            "depth":1
        },
        "5":{
            "id":"5",
            "header":"H1 Child 2",
            "parent_id":"1",
            "order_number":"1",
            "child_count":0,
            "child_ids":[
                
            ],
            "depth":1
        },
        "6":{
            "id":"6",
            "header":"H2 Child 1",
            "parent_id":"2",
            "order_number":"1",
            "child_count":0,
            "child_ids":[
                
            ],
            "depth":1
        },
        "7":{
            "id":"7",
            "header":"H2 Child 2",
            "parent_id":"2",
            "order_number":"1",
            "child_count":4,
            "child_ids":[
                "12",
                "13",
                "14",
                "15"
            ],
            "depth":1
        }
    },
    {
        "12":{
            "id":"12",
            "header":"H2-C2-C1",
            "parent_id":"7",
            "order_number":"1",
            "child_count":0,
            "child_ids":[
                
            ],
            "depth":2
        },
        "13":{
            "id":"13",
            "header":"H2-C2-C2",
            "parent_id":"7",
            "order_number":"2",
            "child_count":0,
            "child_ids":[
                
            ],
            "depth":2
        },
        "14":{
            "id":"14",
            "header":"H2-C2-C3",
            "parent_id":"7",
            "order_number":"3",
            "child_count":0,
            "child_ids":[
                
            ],
            "depth":2
        },
        "15":{
            "id":"15",
            "header":"H2-C2-C4",
            "parent_id":"7",
            "order_number":"4",
            "child_count":0,
            "child_ids":[
                
            ],
            "depth":2
        }
    }
]
```

### Update 1: Get Nodes With No Children

The following function traverses `levels` to extract the nodes with no children

```php
function getNodesWithNoChildren($levels){
   $nodesWithNoChildren = [];
   foreach($levels as $level => $nodes){
      foreach($nodes as $node){
          if($node['child_count']==0){
               $nodesWithNoChildren[]=$node;
          }
      }
   }
   return $nodesWithNoChildren;
}

$nodeNamesWithNoChildren =  array_map(function($node){
  return $node["header"];
}, getNodesWithNoChildren($levels));

echo implode(", ",$nodeNamesWithNoChildren);
```

***Output***

```
Header 3, H1 Child 1, H1 Child 2, H2 Child 1, H2-C2-C1, H2-C2-C2, H2-C2-C3, H2-C2-C4
```

### Update 2: Get Nodes With No Children (Left To Right)

```php
function getLeftToRightNodesWithoutChildren($startNode,$levels){
    $nodesWithNoChildren = [];
    if($startNode == null){
        foreach($levels[0] as $headerNode){
            $subNodes = getLeftToRightNodesWithoutChildren($headerNode,$levels);
            foreach($subNodes as $node){
                $nodesWithNoChildren[]=$node;
            }
        }
    }else{
        if($startNode['child_count']==0){
            $nodesWithNoChildren[]=$startNode;
        }
        foreach($startNode['child_ids'] as $childId){
            $childNode = $levels[$startNode["depth"]+1][$childId];
            $subNodes = getLeftToRightNodesWithoutChildren($childNode,$levels);
            foreach($subNodes as $node){
                $nodesWithNoChildren[]=$node;
            }
        }
    }
    return $nodesWithNoChildren;

}

$nodeNamesWithNoChildren =  array_map(function($node){
  return $node["header"];
}, getLeftToRightNodesWithoutChildren(null,$levels));

echo implode(", ",$nodeNamesWithNoChildren);
```

***Output***

```
H1 Child 1, H1 Child 2, H2 Child 1, H2-C2-C1, H2-C2-C2, H2-C2-C3, H2-C2-C4, Header 3
```

***Getting "array that would contain the IDs of the lowest child"***

```php
$lowest_child = array_map(function($node){
  return $node["id"];
}, getLeftToRightNodesWithoutChildren(null,$levels));

echo implode(", ",$lowest_child);
```

***Output***

```
4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much. When I return `$levels[$depth]` it gives the `H2-C2-C1,H2-C2-C2, H2-C2-C3, H2-C2-C4` which is the lowest, I need also those not lowest but has no more child in the column, I need to get this. `[H1 Child 1, H2 Child 1, H1 Child 2, H2-C2-C1, H2-C2-C2,H2-C2-C3, H2-C2-C4, Header 3]`

Comment: @beginner I've updated the answer to include a function `getNodesWithNoChildren` along with an example of how to use this to achieve the desired output.

Comment: The array must be in correct order just like this `h1 Child 1, H1 Child 2, h2 Child 1, H2 C2 C1, H2 C2 C2, H2 C2 C3, H2 C2 C4, Header 3` How to achieve that? Thank you so much for helping me. I am making a dynamic forms. Their index will be the reference to the input names/id in the rows under these headers.

Comment: I have also another database table for the row labels and then I will just loop in that array and then put input field with id/name of the header_id it corresponds from the array. That's why I need it to be in the exact order. I hope I can explain it better.

Comment: I need the exact order so that in the row I can put `<input type="number" name="input_<?=bottomarray[$current_index]?>"` The user will be able to know that he is inputting data for the `H1 Child 1` column.

Comment: @beginner It is now in the additional order specified

Comment: @beginner see Update 2

Comment: Using another data samples, it seems that the Order number of children are not followed in generating the table. However it gives the correct order of nodeNamesWithNoChildren. I need the generated table to give the exact ordering of the children also. I added the other data sample in the question.

Comment: @beginner unless you can specify what is being used to order the elements, then your question is ambiguous and I cannot assist. This being my final guess, the elements are alphabetically ordered, you could try `asort($nodeNamesWithNoChildren)`;

Comment: the `order_number` in the 4th column is used to order the elements in ascending.

Comment: @beginner see https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: I still cant figure which array to sort. If you still have time please see this https://imgur.com/Ejt4r3u